# Vim substitute a Regex with randomly generated numbers

Tags: vim

Is it possible to substitute a regular expression with a randomly generated number in Vim ? The (random) number to be replaced should be different for each pattern that matches the regular expression. Here's an example of what I need.

Input File:

```
<a>XYZ</a>
<a>XYZ</a>
<a>XYZ</a>
<a>XYZ</a>
```

After substituting XYZ with random numbers, the output could be:

```
<a>599</a>  
<a>14253</a>    
<a>1718</a>
<a>3064</a>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you don't mind a little perl in your vim, you can use

```
:%! perl -pne 's/XYZ/int(rand 1000)/ge'
```

Edit: updated to allow unlimited substitutions on a given line, per suggestion by @hobbes3, so

```
XYZ XYZ
XYZ XYZ XYZ 
XYZ XYZ XYZ XYZ XYZ XYZ
XYZ XYZ
```

Becomes something like

```
86 988
677 477 394 
199 821 193 649 502 471
732 208
```

Comment: Thanks! That is so simple! I didn't know that you could directly run perl from vim.

Comment: You can run *anything* inside vim. See http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1204/save-a-file-you-edited-in-vim-without-the-needed-permissions for a particularly useful example.

Comment: Will that generate a new random int for each line or does it just use a single random int?

Comment: It will generate a new random integer for each line -- the '-n' flag for perl wraps a while loop around the entire program, saying, in effect 'execute this for each line of input', so for each line, it generates a new value for `$random`, then substitutes it for XYZ. Use `perldoc perlrun` at the command prompt to see the perl options in their full glory.

Comment: Using strawberry perl on Windows, I used this syntax: `:%! C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pne "$random=sprintf(\"\%04d\", int(rand 9999)); s/XYZ/$1$random/i;"`

Comment: How do you substitute different numbers for matches within the same line? This only substitute the first match it finds per line. If I add a `g` flag then it'll substitute the same random number to all the matches per line.

Comment: @hobbes3 : this should work: `:%! perl -pne '$r1=int(rand 1000); $r2=int(rand 1000);s/XYZ/$r1/; s/XYZ/$r2/'`

Comment: @BartonChittenden But that's only up to 2 matches? I guess I can find all matches then insert a line break, then do the above solution, but I was just curious if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 6):

Try this: put the below code to a buffer then source it (`:source %`).

```
let rnd = localtime() % 0x10000 

function! Random() 
  let g:rnd = (g:rnd * 31421 + 6927) % 0x10000 
  return g:rnd 
endfun 

function! Choose(n) " 0 n within 
  return (Random() * a:n) / 0x10000 
endfun
```

Then you can do:

```
:s_\(<a>\).*\(</a>\)_\1\=Choose(line('.')*100).\2_
```

Comment: Just for reference this is NOT random. But for the use case it is good enough.