# Replace each match with an incremented number

Tags: regex, perl, vim

I need to add an ID property to a list of objects in a JSON file. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735006/1755152) useful in-line Perl script that replaces each match with a random int.

```
:%! perl -pne 's/XYZ/int(rand 1000)/ge'
```

Assuming I don't know the list's length in advance, how would I replace something like this

```
{
    "id" : XYZ
},
{
    "id" : XYZ
},
{ ... }
```

with this:

```
{
    "id" : 1
},
{
    "id" : 2
},
{ ... }
```

I've tried this:

```
:%! perl -pne 's/XYZ/(0..100)/ge'
```

but that assumes I know the length of the list in advance and also does not work as expected. I know I can get a number of matches using something like this:

```
:%s/"id" : XYZ//gn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-p` already processes the input line by line, so `-n` is redundant.

```
perl -pe 's/XYZ/$i++/ge'
```

`$i++` returns the value of `$i` in numeric context and adds 1 to it.

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to start the counter at 1, so why not `++$i`?

Comment: @zdim: I'm not sure where the OP wants to start: `0..100` seems to start at 0.

Comment: Ah, that, right ... I was looking at the desired output.  Either way, a detail

Comment: @ikegami: I tested the code and it worked. Rolling back.

Comment: wut. I always thought `$i++` does what you said does ("$i++ returns the value of $i and adds 1 to it."), but it doesn't! You need to fix your description, then

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, it also forces numeric context.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that it *doesn't* return the the value of $i when undef.

Comment: Yes, ++ has special behavior on undef specifically to optimize this case: `undef is always treated as numeric, and in particular is changed to 0 before incrementing (so that a post-increment of an undef value will return 0 rather than undef).`

Answer (score 4):

If  you are  doing  this in  Vim and  you  have the  `+perl`
feature then:

```
:%perldo s/XYZ/++$i/e
```

If you want to do it with plain Vim commands, you can follow
the same logic  and use a variable. However, it  needs to be
created beforehand and  incremented after each substitution.
Thus you may need a help from `:g` to execute two commands:

```
:let i=0
:g/XYZ/let i+=1|s//\=i
```

The empty `s//` reuses the pattern from `:g`.

Alternatively,  just  filter  it  through Perl  as  you  did
originally:

```
:%!perl -pe 's/XYZ/++$i/e'
```

Comment: Sadly, don't have Vim compiled with `+perl`, but up-voting since your 3rd suggestion is the same as @choroba 's

Comment: @D_________ `:perldo` is just a quick replacement for the basic filtering example, but there are more nice features involved with this integration. If you use both tools (Perl and Vim) I highly recommend getting a `+perl` Vim and checking the documentation for those commands. a

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl's [built in JSON parser](https://perldoc.pl/JSON::PP) (in 5.14+) you don't need to deal with strings that may show up elsewhere, whether strings and numbers should be quoted or not, or other complications, you can just modify the JSON as a data structure (code will probably need to be altered to modify the correct part of your full JSON structure):

```
perl -0777 -MJSON::PP -E'my $data = decode_json readline; $_->{id} = ++$i foreach @$data; print encode_json $data'
```

Even better would be to use [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) as that will install and use a much faster parser by default.

The `-0777` switch is a [convention](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D) for one-liners to cause readline or the `<>` operator (also used by the -p switch) to return the whole input at once.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a pure Vim solution, here's a more canonical and general solution than in @sidyll's answer that doesn't require `:perldo` nor `:global`, and would also work with multiple matches in a line (adding the `g` flag to `:substitute`):

#### With built-in substitute

In Vim, you can use [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) to replace text with arbitrary expressions. Unfortunately, incrementing a variable is a *statement* in Vim, not an expression. Either one has to resort to tricks like using the length of a List as the counter (`add()` can be used in an expression):

```
:let c = [] | %substitute/XYZ/\=len(add(c, 0))/
```

Or you have to define a separate function (once):

```
function! Increment()
    let g:i += 1
    return g:i
endfunction
let g:i = 0 | %substitute/XYZ/\=Increment()/
```

#### With plugin

The expression syntax is a bit weird (but if you're into Perl, you're used to much worse :-). Also, the explicit separate initialization of the counter (and function) is cumbersome. My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) improves on the built-in `:substitute` command with several variants. Among them `:SubstituteExecute`, which benefits from a predefined context object:

```
:%SubstituteExecute /XYZ/ let v:val.n += 1 | return v:val.n
```

Renumbering is such a frequent task that the plugin even has a special command for it:

```
:Renumber /XYZ/
```

#### Caveats

- A structured but flexible syntax like HTML or JSON is ill suited for parsing with regular expressions, unless you confidently know that the used subset of the allowed syntax is very regular (e.g. because you know the input source and/or have passed the input through a pretty-printer). Prefer specialized tools over generic ones (i.e. use `xmlstarlet` for XML and `jq` for JSON instead of `grep` and `sed`).